# Can't figure out routing on multi-homed machine

Tags: routing, multi-homed

I'm having no success setting up routes and I suspect I have a misconception about what's needed.

On a multihomed machine (Master) with 2 networks (N1 wired, N2 wireless HotSpot), Master can ping every IP on both networks. Great!

Another machine on N1, for example, can ping both of Master's IPs, but can't ping any of the other machines on N2. A machine on N2, can ping both of Master's IPs, but can't ping any of the other machines on N1. I want to correct this by setting up routes.

Am I correct that to allow N1 machines to ping N2 machines, what's needed is a route on Master's N1 network stating that any N2 destination is handled by Master's N2 IP (next hop) and a similar route has to be set up on Master's N2 network stating that any N1 destination is handled by Master's N1 IP (next hop)?

I've tried doing this but it hasn't worked and I think it has to do with the difference between a regular network and the HotSpot. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: i'm no expert and haven't set up such a thing but I have read abotu routing. I'd have thought that your N1 network to have in its routing table, that any packet with an IP that is on N2's subnet, has to be routed to M. So M is the gateway/router to send to, when the packet N wants to send, is on N2.  Or perhaps N1 routes everything to M anyway.  M might need a particular routing table too.  I'd says look at the routing tables on N1, M, and N2.  I guess they are each different subnets?  No doubt N1 and N2 are.. But I guess maybe M is too? I don't know if N1 and N2's subnet can be within M's.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

MASTER has cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward equal to 1, so forwarding is already on. All N1 machines have the N1 IP in MASTER as their gateway and the N2 machines have the N2 IP in MASTER as their gateway. MASTER actually has an N3 network and IP for the Internet connection and everyone can hit the WEB by going through MASTER since MASTER's gateway is the N3 IP. 

Individually, everything works fine when each network machine just wants to hit the WEB. What's not working is a ping from an N1 machine to an N2 machine and vice versa.

Comment: All the N2 devices are smartphones and tablets so I installed ssh on an N2 tablet and I can successfully start a session as long as I start it from MASTER, but an attempt to start it from an N1 machine fails. It's obvious that N1 traffic is not making it to N2 for some reason.

I think it has something to do with N2 being a wireless HotSpot. I tried tcpdump-ing traffic from MASTER and discovered that tcpdump is deaf to traffic on MASTER's N2 IP with the exception that I see periodic who-has packets. A ping on MASTER against MASTER's own N2 IP work, but tcpdump doesn't show any output.

Comment: Doing a ping from an N2 machine against MASTER's N2 IP again shows no tcpdump traffic but the pings work. Something inside the HotSpot code is eating packets before even tcpdump can see them so I have no way of observing traffic on that NIC. It's the periodic who-has traffic that tells me tcpdump is working but deaf to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The hosts (and other routers besides Master) on N1 need a route pointing traffic for the N2 subnet at Master's **N1** address as the gateway. The hosts (and other routers besides Master) on N2 need a route pointing the N1 subnet at Master's **N2** address.

Master needs to be told to do IP forwarding. On most Unix-like OSes this is usually done via setting a kernel variable via sysctl. But the exact path to the variable is different in different OSes, so check your OS documentation for things like "net.ipv4.ip_forward" or "net.inet.ip.forward".